# Pyparsing: the differences between MatchFirst, Or, and oneOf

Tags: pyparsing

in Pyparsing, what are the differences between MatchFirst, Or, and oneOf

when there are shared characters in the strings like

word, wording, words

Or(['word', 'wording', 'words'])

MatchFirst(['word', 'wording', 'words'])

oneOf(['word', 'wording', 'words'])

Answer (score 7):

From the online docs (https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/)

- `MatchFirst` - If two expressions match, the first one listed is the one that will match.
- `Or` -  If two expressions match, the expression that matches the longest string will be used.
- `oneOf` - Helper to quickly define a set of alternative Literals, and makes sure to do longest-first testing when there is a conflict, regardless of the input order, but returns a MatchFirst for best performance.

`MatchFirst` tests the current parse location with each string in its constructor, stopping at the first one to match.

`Or` tests the current parse location against all of the strings given in its constructor, and will return the longest match.

`oneOf` generates a `Regex` or `MatchFirst` to match the longest match, by reordering the input list when there are alternatives with common start strings to test the longer string first.

Answer (score 0):

`oneOf` operates on `str` understood as space separated strings and can be simplistically defined as

```
oneOf = lambda xs: Or(Literal(x) for x in xs.split(" "))
```

While `Or` operates on expressions - `ParseElement` instances.
So you can see either `oneOf` as specialization of `Or` or `Or` being a generalization of `oneOf`.

You can write `oneOf('foo bar')` as `Literal('foo') ^ Literal('bar')`
but you can't write every `Or` expression using `oneOf`.

`MatchFirst` is the same as `Or` except conflict resolution method - `Or` yields the longest match while `MatchFirst` returns the first match in definition order.

So

```
expr = Literal('bar') ^ Words(alphanums)
expr.parseString("barstool").asList() == ["barstool"]
```

but

```
expr = Literal('bar') | Words(alphanums)
expr.parseString("barstool").asList() == ["bar"]
```